# Typescript concat two data types array in one

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

How do I concat two types array in one array using `concat`. If I initialize it with two data types it works fine but when I `concat` it. Typescript throws an error that both types are incompatible.

```
const foo: string[] = ['hello', 'world'];
const bar: number[] = [1, 2];
const both: (string | number)[] = foo.concat(bar); // gets an error on bar

const other: (string | number)[] = ['hello', 'world', 2, 3]; // this works
```

Comment: Please be aware that array data structure itself should have only one type of elements. What you are trying to create called `tuple`. Type of each element of the `tuple` should be typed upfront. `const tuple:[string,number]=['str', 42]`. Furthermore V8 works better with homogeneous arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it has to do with the implementation of `.concat()` in Typescript. It is implemented as the type of the merged array is expected to be the type of `foo` here. That is the reason it is throwing an error.

You can check the error tab for your code snippet from [Typescript Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuG0BOBLMBzA2gXRgF4ZcByACwFMAbGkMgGhjIHcQ0aATM-AbgBQoSLABGAQzQowAVwC2oqmgLFSARmYAmfkPDQYokFAooAFOizYYAHxiyFSgJQqSCEADphwcVFMS0jkA) to understand more about this.

If you want to make it work, you can use the spread operator. It should work fine.

```js
const foo: string[] = ['hello', 'world'];
const bar: number[] = [1, 2];
const both: (string | number)[] = [...foo, ...bar];
```

Comment: hi @bharadhwaj . could you explain why we concat foo: Array<string> and bar Array<number> and got  both: string?

Comment: @glushkina1 Arrays are implicitly meant to hold a single datatype, whereas it is tuples that are allocated for storing different types of datatypes. So when we try to concatinate two arrays typescript just look for the type of the first array and decide the type of the resultant array with that.